# При написании запроса с Include() на c#, возникает проблема на фронте (JS) с Fetch API

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

Изучаю Web Api. Бэк на c#, на фронте использую JS с Fetch API.
Пример неработающего кода с Include():

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Student>> GetStudent(int id)
    {
        var student = await _context.Students.Include(x => x.Group).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
        if (student == null)
            return BadRequest();
        return new ObjectResult(student);
    }
```

и JS :

```
async function GetStudent(id) {
    fetch("/api/student/" + id)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data));
}
```

Вот что выдает Postman при запросе
[image]

Отношение классов = Group - Student: Один ко многим.

Почему не работает?

Как я понял, нужно сериализовать данные Group, но я не знаю на каком этапе.

Сущность Student:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
    public List<IndividalLesson> IndividalLessons { get; set; } = new List<IndividalLesson>();
```

Group:

```
public int id { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public ClassTeacher ClassTeacher { get; set; }
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; } = new List<Student>();
    public List<Lesson> Lessons { get; set; } = new List<Lesson>();
```

P.S. Без Include() все работает прекрасно

Comment: Покажите определение сущностей Student и Group.

Answer (score 0):

Это перевод ответа отсюда: [JSON.NET Error Self referencing loop detected for type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18223985/1101913).
А тот, в свою очередь, перепечатан отсюда: [Loop Reference handling in Web API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/hongyes/loop-reference-handling-in-web-api).

### Способ 1: Глобальное игнорирование циклических ссылок

Сериализатор JSON.NET предоставляет возможность игнорировать циклические ссылки. Для этого, поместите следующий код в файл `WebApiConfig.cs`:

```cs
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling 
= Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

Этот способ заставит сериализатор игнорировать цепочки ссылочных свойств, обход которых приводит к зацикливанию. Однако у него есть минусы:

- Теряется информация о циклических связях
- Работает только с JSON.NET
- Невозможно контролировать уровень вложенности, при котором цепочка свойств определяется как циклическая

Чтобы использовать этот способ в обычном ASP.NET проекте, добавьте указанную выше строку в Global.asax.cs, но сначала добавьте это:

```cs
var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
```

Чтобы использовать этот способ в проекте .Net Core, измените Startup.cs таким образом:

```cs
var mvc = services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
       ...
    })
    .AddJsonOptions(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

### Способ 2: Глобальное сохранение циклических ссылок

Второй способ похож на первый. Просто измените код так:

```cs
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling 
     = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;     
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling 
     = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
```

После применения этого способа, структура данных изменится таким образом:

```json
[
   {
      "$id":"1",
      "Category":{
         "$id":"2",
         "Products":[
            {
               "$id":"3",
               "Category":{
                  "$ref":"2"
               },
               "Id":2,
               "Name":"Yogurt"
            },
            {
               "$ref":"1"
            }
         ],
         "Id":1,
         "Name":"Diary"
      },
      "Id":1,
      "Name":"Whole Milk"
   },
   {
      "$ref":"3"
   }
]
```

Ключевые слова $Id и $ref позволяют сохранить все ссылки оставляя граф объекта плоским. Но клиентский код должен понимать такую структуру JSON объекта. Это решение также применимо только к сериализатору JSON.NET.

### Способ 3: Игнорирование или сохранение циклических ссылок при помощи атрибутов

Этот способ заключается в том, чтобы добавить в сериализуемый класс атрибуты для управления поведением сериализации на уровне класса или свойства.

Чтобы игнорировать свойство:

```cs
public class Category 
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
   
    [JsonIgnore] 
    [IgnoreDataMember] 
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; } 
}
```

Атрибут JsonIgnore предназначен для JSON.NET, а IgnoreDataMember - для XmlDCSerializer.

Чтобы сохранить ссылку:

```cs
// Fix 3 
[JsonObject(IsReference = true)] 
public class Category 
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
 
   // Fix 3 
   //[JsonIgnore] 
   //[IgnoreDataMember] 
   public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; } 
} 

[DataContract(IsReference = true)] 
public class Product 
{ 
   [Key] 
   public int Id { get; set; } 

   [DataMember] 
   public string Name { get; set; } 

   [DataMember] 
   public virtual Category Category { get; set; } 
}
```

Атрибут `JsonObject(IsReference = true)]` предназначен для JSON.NET, а `[DataContract](IsReference = true)]` предназначен для XmlDCSerializer. Обратите внимание: после добавления `DataContract` к классу вам необходимо добавить `DataMember` к свойствам, которые вы хотите сериализовать.

Атрибуты могут применяться как c сериализатором JSON.NET, так и c XML-сериализатором и предоставляют больше возможностей для управления сериализацией.

Comment: Спасибо, ответ помог. Однако из всех способов сработал только первый (для asp net core 3 и выше нужно ещё скачать библиотеку Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson).